# returning a pointer and modifying what that pointer points to

Tags: c, pointers, memory, linked-list

I have a pointer in one function and i would like to return that pointer so that i can modify what it points to later on. Will returning it return the address of what the pointer is pointing to or the pointer itself? This question is because i want to change what the head of a linked-list points to.

So for example

```
struct node_{
    //variables
}*headPtr=NULL; //assume when we are returning headPtr in foo() it is no longer NULL but points to something

typdef struct node_ node;

node foo(){
    //some if conditions
    return headPtr;
}

main(){
    node *tmpPtr;
    tmpPtr=foo();
}
```

Comment: what have you got in the `//some if conditions`? i guess you need to use `malloc()`

Answer (score 0):

This function takes a pointer to the head of a linked list, some other arguments, creates a new node and append the list to it and return de new head.

```
 struct type *ptr_change_head(struct type *ptr_old_head, other args){
  struct type *ptr = ptr_old_head;
  struct type *ptr_new_head = <new head>;

  ptr_new_head->ptr_next = ptr;

  return ptr_new_head;

}
```

Comment: I advise against new-pointer return values for the precise reason that communicating an error condition to the *caller* is severely limited (and at least one hole will always be present). Ex: Assuming you fixed this code to check for NULL prior to using `ptr` you may return NULL and hope the caller saved the original passed pointer to avoid a leak). This is unfortunately not uncommon, and in fact a commonly used standard-function (`realloc()`) is routinely used incorrectly for precisely this reason. None-the-less, this does address the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's make your types match up.  `foo()`'s type signature says it returns a `node`, but you are actually trying to return a pointer to `node`.  Let's redefined `foo()` to be

```
node *foo() {
    return headPtr;
}
```

> Will returning it return the address of what the pointer is pointing to or the pointer itself?

The line

```
tmpPtr = foo();
```

will place into the variable `tmpPtr` the address of what the pointer is pointing to, and `tmpPtr` will be another variable that exactly matches `headPtr`.  That is to say, two separate pointers that point to the same thing.  There are two separate points to make here:

- `tmpPtr` and `headPtr` are two separate variables, and if you re-assign one it will have no effect on the other.
- Since they currently point to the same node, you *could* potentially mutate the node that they point to by dereferencing either pointer, assuming they point to an actual node and not `NULL`.

If your intent is to change what `headPtr` points to you can either:

- change `headPtr` directly with an assignment like `headPtr = something`.
- set up a pointer to `headPtr` with type `node**`.

You can set up a pointer to `headPtr` with something like

```
node **foo() {
    return &headPtr;
}

int main() {
    node **headPtrPtr = foo();
    *headPtrPtr = something else;
}
```

This will place into `headPtrPtr` a pointer to `headPtr`.  By dereferencing `headPtrPtr`, you can make `headPtr` point to a new node.